# query database datetime field for all rows with full hour in django

Tags: sql, django, django-models

I have a table with sensor data, resistor values, captured every minute;

My app is django-2, python3, mysql;

Is it possibel somehow with django queries to select only the rows where my datetime field has i.e. the minute==0, so I get data entries with regular intervals??

Similar to this (object_list has no results)

```
 object_list = SensorData_01.objects.filter(dtime__minute=0)
```

I just read all the awesome filter functions in django docs, and saw the dates() and datetimes() comparison functions; But my issue was not explained there.

Comment: What is not working with the given queryset?

Comment: well, there is 0 results. But there are dozens of entries with minute zero

Comment: Do you use a MySQL database? Is `USE_TZ` enabled?

Comment: USE_TZ is enabled; But this is my heating controller and only used by me so i could change that, if it is a problem.

Comment: well some MySQL databases lack the timezone info: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/troubleshooting/mysql_can_not_extract_filter_on_attributes_of_a_date_time_object_when_timezones_are_enabled.html

Comment: I just tried again, __year is working properly, month and day return 0 results. And also hour and minute cannot find anything

Comment: well thanks, it worked to populate my mysql db with timezone as said here https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysql_tzinfo_to_sql/

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to populate the mysql timezone tables as stated herer https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysql_tzinfo_to_sql/ thanks to Willems hint in comments above

shell> mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root mysql